# Color consistency between Photoshop, iPhone Simulator, and iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator, photoshop, adobe-illustrator, calibration

I've been working a lot with Photoshop .psd files recently and have been bouncing back and forth a lot to ensure colors look just right on the iPhone.

Can anyone offer some tips on calibrating macbook/apple cinema displays in regards to keeping color consistency between Photoshop, the iPhone simulator, and physical iPhones?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look on [LiveView created by Nicholas Zambetti](http://zambetti.com/projects/liveview/).

You need to install it on your iPad/iPhone/iPod Touch and on your Mac. when synced (Mac and device) you can have a preview of the selected area of your screen (Mac), on your device.

Hope this will help you out!

Cheers,

vfn

Comment: +1 for LiveView. It's perfect for seeing how colors on your macbook, in photoshop, etc. will look on your iPhone's screen.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the problem:  One day my graphic designer and I wanted to match colors with her calibrated Apple monitor.  We compared several different devices (my 3GS, her iPod Touch, my iPhone4, and an iPad).  The color temperature and calibration was different on all 4 devices.  Furthermore, my 3GS showed a much cooler color temperature another friend's newer 3GS.  And there are similar reports of differences between the production runs of other iDevice models.

So you will have to check your colors on several different devices.

Comment: I was going to say the same thing, that I had observed color differences across devices.  All you can go is make it look good on average.

Comment: Now is year 2013, I wonder if anything changes on color consistency?