# App's icon color is always darker on the iPhone than it is on the iOS simulator or when viewing the image online

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode5, photoshop, iphone-4

I have been trying to solve this app icon color issue all morning. I am still experiencing this after going through both of these highly recommended photoshop/iOS design articles:

1. http://davidmckinney.com/blog/2013/12/31/designing-iphone-apps-how-to-setup-photoshop
2. http://bjango.com/articles/photoshop/

Here is the problem that I am having:

When creating my app's icon, the color that I see in Photoshop is the exact same color that I see in xcode's asset catalog. It is also perfect when I run the app on the iOS simulator.

However, when I run my app on my iPhone the app icon's color is always darker.

What's weird, is if I take a screenshot of my iPhone's screen and email it to myself, the color is correct! So for some reason the color is only darker when you are actually looking at the iPhone's screen.

Pardon my ignorance, but this is the first design I have ever done for an iOS app and I don't understand why this is happening or how to fix it.

EDIT: I am now using [LiveView](http://zambetti.com/projects/liveview/) after reading this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3597221/3344977

What's funny is no matter how hard I try I cannot get the color I see on my screen to appear on my iPhone screen. It's as if this shade of Pink I'm trying to use just isn't possible to render on an iPhone display.

Comment: Have you tried changing the brightness on your iPhone?

Comment: Turning up the iPhone's brightness setting does not help. The color is still wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your iPhone and Monitor screens have different color calibrations (if that's the right term)

You're going to want to setup a color profile on your computer that matches the iPhone screens as closely as possible, and use that when developing icons.

Comment: So how do developers and designers tackle this issue then?

Comment: Any idea on how to figure out the correct iPhone screen color profile? I've been searching around for this stuff and the best I found were the 2 articles listed in my question and those have not helped.

Comment: You're gonna have to find some guide on calibrating monitor colors for iOS design. You can always just load up a reference image on both your  iPhone and monitor and adjust your computers settings until they look similar.

Comment: I selected your answer because your exact verbage led me to this old answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3597221/3344977

Answer (score 1):

> for some reason the color is only darker when you are actually looking at the iPhone's screen

Consider turning up the brightness on your iPhone. Go to Settings->Wallpapers & Brightness to adjust it.

In any case, the issue isn't that the value of the color is changing on your device, it's just that that color value is being rendered differently.

Comment: Turning up the iPhone's brightness setting does not help. The color is still wrong. So how can I fix this and make sure that the color is rendered correctly? I need the color I see on my iPhone, to match the color in Photoshop, the asset catalog, and on the iOS simulator.

Comment: AFAIK there's no way to calibrate the screen of an iOS device, so adjusting the device is out. That leaves adjusting your monitor to match your device, but that's only a reasonable solution if you only care about that one device.

Answer (score 0):

Its because the resolution of your screen is different than your iOS device try it on other device

Comment: I don't believe resolution is the issue here, more likely gamma and contrast disparities.